# How to make a home made pre-workout in bulk, at "home"?

Tags: supplements, pre-workout

I was about to order the supplements for my pre workout till I realized something. I won't be able to measure each time I'm going for a workout session. I've been stuck with a pencil and paper trying to see if I could figure out how to make one serving equal to the amount of supplements I need for a single session, maybe I'm not as smart as I thought haha.

Would anyone be willing to help?
Supplements: 
Beta Alanine
Creatine
Citrulline Mallate
BCAA
Gatorade(everything above is pure, need a sweetner)

P:S: It's my first time taking pre workouts. I get the feeling I'll soon drop some of the supplements I listed. I'll have days where I won't have beta alanine or BCAA, something like that - to see which one I need. I'll be taking caffeine in pill form

I've also searched for tutorials online but didn't find anything

Would anyone be willing to help?

Comment: With regards to ingredient choice, BCAAs are almost useless (you already get them in most things that have protein), Caffeine is pretty straightforward, Beta Alanine isn't just for pre-workout, Citrulline Mallate is good, and Creatine Monohydrate or Creatine HCL (HCL has a sour taste that might pair well with Gatorade) is a fantastic option not mentioned here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the arithmetic what you're having a hard time with? You just need to determine what dosage you want to use and weigh out a large batch of it all.

For example let's look at a practical serving size for each ingredient,

- 02.00 grams, Beta Alanine
- 06.00 grams, Citrulline Mallate
- 15.00 grams, BCAAs

Now if you wanted a 30 day supply, you just need a large container you can seal and shake. Then you would weigh out 30 times what each serving size is. Meaning that you would add 60 grams of Beta Alanine, 180 grams of Citrulline Mallate, and 450 grams of BCAAs. Once you have everything in the large container, you would shake it vigorously until everything was well blended. Then you would add up the weight of your individual serving dosages and that would be the weight of your preworkout blend's individual serving dosage. Which in this case would be 23 grams.

Alternatively, you could get little tiny bags ([like these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JCM5LGM)) and by using a microgram scale, portion out individual servings. This would be much more tedious to prepare, but also more accurate in the final consumed product.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out!

Comment: On second thought, this would actually work. I've been doing lots of calculus lately and you wouldn't believe the stupid formulas I've been using